Systemctl not restarting symfony messenger consumer
I have a Symfony (6.4) messenger consumer that processes some background queues.
As mentioned in the documentation is a good practice to restart it every hour.
So I am using systemctl to handle it.
When I launch systemctl start myservice everything is fine, after an hour, the service stops, but is never relaunched again.
Here is my service configuration file for systemctl
[Unit]
Description=Symfony messenger-consume
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/webapplication/bin/console messenger:consume async --time-limit=10 -vv
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
User=sysops
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

The systemctl status of my service (after it stops)
messenger-worker.service - Symfony messenger-consume
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/messenger-worker.service, enabled)
    Active: failed (failed)

I tried using the following configuration, but in my case, it does not change a thing.
[Unit]
Description=Symfony messenger-consume
StartLimitInterval=200
StartLimitBurst=5
After=network.target

### ...

And finally if you need the log when I start the service
INFO:systemctl:EXEC BEGIN /usr/bin/systemctl start messenger-worker--system
DEBUG:systemctl:======= systemctl.py start messenger-worker
DEBUG:systemctl:found 20 sysd files
DEBUG:systemctl:found 5 sysv files
INFO:systemctl:system is offline
DEBUG:systemctl:/etc/systemd/system/messenger-worker.service no --user mode >> accept
DEBUG:systemctl:[29] 0. trying messenger-worker.service.lock _______
DEBUG:systemctl:[29] 0. holding lock on messenger-worker.service.lock
DEBUG:systemctl: start unit messenger-worker.service => /etc/systemd/system/messenger-worker.service
DEBUG:systemctl:extra-vars []
DEBUG:systemctl:  file time: 2024-05-24 02:47:07.761767
DEBUG:systemctl:  boot time: 2024-05-24 02:47:00.077767
DEBUG:systemctl:reading /var/run/messenger-worker.service.status
DEBUG:systemctl:  file time: 2024-05-24 02:47:07.761767
DEBUG:systemctl:  boot time: 2024-05-24 02:47:00.077767
DEBUG:systemctl:reading /var/run/messenger-worker.service.status
DEBUG:systemctl:ExecStart[0]: /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/webapplication/bin/console messenger:consume async --time-limit=10 -vv
DEBUG:systemctl:  file time: 2024-05-24 02:47:07.761767
DEBUG:systemctl:  boot time: 2024-05-24 02:47:00.077767
DEBUG:systemctl:reading /var/run/messenger-worker.service.status
INFO:systemctl:simple start '/usr/local/bin/php' '/var/www/webapplication/bin/console' 'messenger:consume' 'async' '--time-limit=10' '-vv'
DEBUG:systemctl:  file time: 2024-05-24 02:47:07.761767
DEBUG:systemctl:  boot time: 2024-05-24 02:47:00.077767
DEBUG:systemctl:reading /var/run/messenger-worker.service.status
DEBUG:systemctl:simple process for /etc/systemd/system/messenger-worker.service
DEBUG:systemctl:writing to /var/run/messenger-worker.service.status
        MainPID=30
INFO:systemctl:simple started PID 30
DEBUG:systemctl:  file time: 2024-05-24 02:47:18.059518
DEBUG:systemctl:  boot time: 2024-05-24 02:47:00.077767
DEBUG:systemctl:  file time: 2024-05-24 02:47:18.059518
DEBUG:systemctl:  boot time: 2024-05-24 02:47:00.077767
DEBUG:systemctl:reading /var/run/messenger-worker.service.status
DEBUG:systemctl:pid_file '/var/run/messenger-worker.service.status' => PID 30

If you need further information, please let me know.
For your information, I did my tests with a --time-limit of 10 seconds.

you need to use something like supervisor to restart your consumer. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#deploying-to-production

Yes that is why i am using systemctl.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#messenger-systemd
And according to the doc: "While Supervisor is a great tool, it has the disadvantage that you need system access to run it."
